# Find unused and duplicate indexes

Tags: sql-server, index

Please let us know how can I find out unused and duplicate indexes from SQL servers, I searched in Google but there is no good information.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.
But bear in mind that after you get a list of bad/unused indexes make sure you fully understand who has created them and what for.

If no one can tell you and there is no docs on them you better do not touch them anyway.

- configure job to get statistic of usage of those indexes and run it
  for a considerable amount of time to make sure indexes are not used
  at all(monthly/quarterly reports);
- after you are sure about the   indexes - disable them and pau
  attention to perf changes in your    system.

#### Possible bad indexes:

```
    SELECT OBJECT_NAME(s.[object_id])   AS [Table Name],
       i.name                       AS [Index Name],
       i.index_id,
       i.is_disabled,
       i.is_hypothetical,
       i.has_filter,
       i.fill_factor,
       user_updates                 AS [Total Writes],
       user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups AS [Total Reads],
       user_updates -(user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups) AS [Difference]
FROM   sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats  AS s WITH (NOLOCK)
       INNER JOIN sys.indexes       AS i WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON  s.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
            AND i.index_id = s.index_id
WHERE  OBJECTPROPERTY(s.[object_id], 'IsUserTable') = 1
       AND s.database_id = DB_ID()
       AND user_updates > (user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups)
       AND i.index_id > 1
ORDER BY
       [Total Reads] ASC OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

#### Overlapping indexes:

```
;WITH CTE_INDEX_DATA AS (
       SELECT
              SCHEMA_DATA.name AS schema_name,
              TABLE_DATA.name AS table_name,
              INDEX_DATA.name AS index_name,
              STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.name + ' ' + CASE WHEN INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END -- Include column order (ASC / DESC)

                                  FROM    sys.tables AS T
                                                INNER JOIN sys.indexes INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS
                                                ON T.object_id = INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id
                                                INNER JOIN sys.index_columns INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS
                                                ON INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id = INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id
                                                AND INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.index_id = INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.index_id
                                                INNER JOIN sys.columns COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS
                                                ON T.object_id = COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id
                                                AND INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.column_id = COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.column_id
                                  WHERE   INDEX_DATA.object_id = INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id
                                                AND INDEX_DATA.index_id = INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.index_id
                                                AND INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.is_included_column = 0
                                  ORDER BY INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.key_ordinal
                                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS key_column_list ,
          STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.name
                                  FROM    sys.tables AS T
                                                INNER JOIN sys.indexes INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS
                                                ON T.object_id = INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id
                                                INNER JOIN sys.index_columns INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS
                                                ON INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id = INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id
                                                AND INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.index_id = INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.index_id
                                                INNER JOIN sys.columns COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS
                                                ON T.object_id = COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id
                                                AND INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.column_id = COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.column_id
                                  WHERE   INDEX_DATA.object_id = INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id
                                                AND INDEX_DATA.index_id = INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.index_id
                                                AND INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.is_included_column = 1
                                  ORDER BY INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.key_ordinal
                                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS include_column_list,
       INDEX_DATA.is_disabled -- Check if index is disabled before determining which dupe to drop (if applicable)
       FROM sys.indexes INDEX_DATA
       INNER JOIN sys.tables TABLE_DATA
       ON TABLE_DATA.object_id = INDEX_DATA.object_id
       INNER JOIN sys.schemas SCHEMA_DATA
       ON SCHEMA_DATA.schema_id = TABLE_DATA.schema_id
       WHERE TABLE_DATA.is_ms_shipped = 0
       AND INDEX_DATA.type_desc IN ('NONCLUSTERED', 'CLUSTERED')
)
SELECT
       *
FROM CTE_INDEX_DATA DUPE1
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM CTE_INDEX_DATA DUPE2
 WHERE DUPE1.schema_name = DUPE2.schema_name
 AND DUPE1.table_name = DUPE2.table_name
 AND (DUPE1.key_column_list LIKE LEFT(DUPE2.key_column_list, LEN(DUPE1.key_column_list)) OR DUPE2.key_column_list LIKE LEFT(DUPE1.key_column_list, LEN(DUPE2.key_column_list)))
 AND DUPE1.index_name <> DUPE2.index_name)
```

**Reference:**
[Finding and Eliminating Duplicate or Overlapping Indexes](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Indexing/110106/) (Edward Pollack, SQLServerCentral.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sp_BlitzIndex to get a detailed report on duplicate indexes, overlapping indexes, unused indexes and much more. While designing any index there are other moving parts that needs to be considered.

Please check https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/